# How do you create a list of VALUES to be used inside a complex sql query with pg-promise?

Tags: sql, pg-promise

I have a rather complex query that I'm trying to put togehter with pg-promise:

`sqlfile.sql`

```
WITH insert_and_return AS
  (
    INSERT INTO myTable
      (param_01, param_02, param_03, param_id)
    VALUES
      (${param_01}, ${param_02}, ${param_03}, uuid_generate_v4())  
    RETURNING
      param_id
  )

named_data (name, values) AS
  (
    VALUES
      ${pairs}
  )

INSERT INTO anotherTable
  SELECT ir.param_id, nd.name, nd.values
  FROM insert_and_return AS ir, named_data AS nd;
```

I need the `${pairs}` to look like the output of the `pgp.helpers.values`, a series of values inside parenthesis (https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.values)

Query execution looks like this:

```
const data = { one: ['one'], two: ['two']};
// transform to data_pairs
const data_pairs = [ {key: 'one', value: ['one']}, {key: 'two', value: ['tow']} ];

const pairs = pgp.helper.values(data_pairs, ['key', 'value']);
// ('one',array['one']),('two',array['two'])

query = pgp.as.format(sqlFile, { param_01, param_02, param_03, pairs })
await db.none(query)
```

The final `query` appears to put another set of quotes around `pairs` values.

`// '(''one'',array[''one'']),(''two'',array[''two''])'`

Can someone recommend a way to generate a set of values like `pairs` to be used inside a sql query file without the added quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic double-escaping (double-formatting) mistake.

The value of `pairs` is already pre-formatted, so it should be used as `${pairs:raw}` inside SQL, to avoid being escaped for the second time.

See [Raw Text](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#raw-text) filter.

Also, instead of this code:

```
query = pgp.as.format(sqlFile, { param_01, param_02, param_03, pairs })
await db.none(query)
```

you can just write it like this:

```
await db.none(sqlFile, { param_01, param_02, param_03, pairs });
```

Comment: missed this in the docs. makes perfect sense. thank you!!

Comment: @M.Holmes You're welcome. See also the shorter way to execute such queries ;)